# Jquery - check href in link expression issue?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I stuck on the expression that check if address contains variable. Jquery returns error: unrecognized expression: .ui-body h3 a[href*=/65_] . Can you help me with this please. Thank you very much.
PS: I need that slash in href expression with number and underscore because of duplicity in links. Slash in expression is problem !

Jquery:

```
num_id = 65
$(".ui-body h2 a[href*=\/" + num_id + "]_").first().parent().parent().parent().append($(this));
```

HTML:
    ..content

```
<div class="col-bottom-1">
  <div class="ui-body">
   <h2>
     <a href="/65_news.html">Text</a>
     <a href="/65_news.html">&gt;&gt;</a>
   </h2>
  </div>
  <!-- this is place where I display div after Jquery function -->
</div>
```

Comment: Are you trying to get the href value? Then change it? Please be a bit more specific on what you want to happen. Thanks, help us help you

Comment: Why not `col-bottom-1 .ui-body h2 a`?

Comment: It's just example. In real code It's more complicated it works great on site but there is duplicity without / in href expression. For example Link href 1265_ and 65_. Thats why I need that slash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing it's supposed to be

```
 $(".ui-body h2 a[href*='/" + num_id + "_']")
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/pNhZ9/)

don't escape inside the brackets, and make sure all characters (the underscore) are actually inside the brackets

Answer (score 2):

You must escape your `/` to use it as selector and your `_` must be inside the href attribute selector.

[Ref](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/):

> To use any of the meta-characters ( such as 
>   !"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[]^`{|}~ ) as a literal part of a name, it must
>   be escaped with with two backslashes: \. For example, an element with
>   id="foo.bar", can use the selector $("#foo\.bar"). The W3C CSS
>   specification contains the complete set of rules regarding valid CSS
>   selectors. Also useful is the blog entry by Mathias Bynens on CSS
>   character escape sequences for identifiers.

Like:

```
num_id = 65
$(".ui-body h2 a[href*=\\/" + num_id + "_]").first().parent().parent().parent().append($(this));
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/GUDYN/

Comment: Right answer. Thank you for your time and effort.

Comment: I don't understand, is this the answer to be accepted or the other?